# lateinitVar cannot be resolved to use isInitialized from Kotlin 1.2.10

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-lateinit

I want to use [this feature](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#lateinit-top-level-properties-and-local-variables)

the simplest thing like in the example does not work for me:

```
lateinit val foo = 1
val bar = foo::lateinitVar.isInitialized()
```

But I am getting

```
unresolved reference lateinitVar
```

I am using Kotlin 1.2.10 via gradle in Android-Studio (also the Kotlin 1.2.10 plugin installed there)

Comment: Can you share the code?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There’s no variable with name `lateinitVar` in your code, thus the error. Look at the example again:

```
this::lateinitVar.isInitialized
```

There’s a variable `lateinitVar` defined in `this`, which the function is called on. The code snippet in the example can be expanded (little plus sign at the beginning of the listing) and looks as follows:

```
class Foo {
    lateinit var lateinitVar: String

    fun initializationLogic() {
        println("isInitialized before assignment: " + this::lateinitVar.isInitialized)
        lateinitVar = "value"
        println("isInitialized after assignment: " + this::lateinitVar.isInitialized)    

    }
}
```

This might make it more clear.

Also, be aware that `lateinit` can’t be applied to `val` but only `var`.

Comment: Ah thanks - was reading the example wrong - so it is just ::foo.isInitialized()