# How to perform companion object lateinit is initiallize check

Tags: kotlin

If I have a lateinit variable, I could check is it initialized using (this::lateInitVar.isInitialized), as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47860466/3286489

However if the variable is a companion object, how could I do so?

e.g.

```
class MyClass {

    companion object {
        lateinit var myGlobalLateInit: String
    }

    lateinit var myLocalLateInit: String

    fun settingVariable() {
        if (!this::myLocalLateInit.isInitialized) {
            myLocalLateInit = "I am set"
        }

        if (!MyClass::myGloablLateInit.isInitialized) { // This line will error out. How could I set it?
            myGloablLateInit = "I am set"
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Personally, I'd just not make it lateinit and set it to null instead, and check for that

Answer (score 7):

You could extract it into a function inside the companion object:

```
class MyClass {

    companion object {
        lateinit var myGlobalLateInit: String

        fun isMyGlobalLateInitInitialized() = ::myGlobalLateInit.isInitialized
    }

    fun settingVariable() {
        if (!isMyGlobalLateInitInitialized()) {
            myGlobalLateInit = "I am set"
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: this is the perfect approach for companion object +1